# Block direct access to php files with rewrite

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm building a very simple API, but I want to block direct access to php files.

My current .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on 
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase / 


RewriteRule ^api/(.*) $1.php/ [L]
```

So if i go to www.website.com/api/register it should call the register.php file. This works fine, but I want to block somebody from giong to www.website.com/register.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an

```
RewriteRule (.*)\.php /$1 [L,R=301]
```

before your current rule

Comment: You're being too nice, make it a 403, or 418 response :)